# Deleting records from nested tables MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, parent-child, crud

I am having trouble with deleting from 3 nested tables that I have.

When I try and delete a record from the first table, it gives me an error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted
>   with the REFERENCE constraint

The delete action method is :

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Parent parent = db.Parent.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ParentID == id);
        foreach(var item in parent.Child.ToList())
        {
            db.Child.Remove(item);
            foreach (var grand in item.Grand.ToList())
            {
                db.Grand.Remove(grand);
            }
        }
        db.Parent.Remove(parent);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I would really appreciate any help on this problem
Also, if someone can direct me to a tutorial on CRUD operations for nested tables that would help me out a lot.

Comment: First you need to delete the record from question table because you add FK in question table, that's why you cant delete the primary key till you delete all you record containing the FK.

Comment: You are trying to delete data that are referenced in other tables : you can't do that. Either drop the constraint, delete your data and recreate the constraint OR delete the data that is referenced by the Foreign Key first. (FK means Foreign Key, that's your error message)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to all this. If an example could be provided I will appreciate it.

Comment: @Eyad Follow the Example [Here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s04.html) . hope it help you.

Comment: @Eyad Basically, put the `db.Question.Remove(item)` after your `foreach (var option in item.Options)
            {
                db.Option.Remove(option);
            }`

Comment: @Hyarantar I have done that but I get another error:  System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: IT worked , I didn't realise that I deleted a tiny part of the code after I posted the problem. Put everything back to the code above, changed the Question.Remove to where you suggested and it WORKED :) . Thank you so much @Hyarantar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working code thanks to Hyarantar

```
 public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Parent parent = db.Parent.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ParentID == id);
    foreach(var item in parent.Child.ToList())
    {
        foreach (var grand in item.Grand.ToList())
        {
            db.Grand.Remove(grand);
        }
        db.Child.Remove(item);  
    }
    db.Parent.Remove(parent);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I only needed to change the order of removing the items, so db.Child.Remove(item) has been placed after the loop for deleting the options.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working in MVC 5 For deleting child entities by deleting Parent entity

public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id, Recipee Recipe_Id)
        {

```
        if (Recipe_Id != null)
        {
            using (RecipeeStoreEntities1 context = new RecipeeStoreEntities1())
            {
                var masterData = context.Recipees.Include("Ingredients").Where(p => p.Recipe_Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

                var childData = masterData.Ingredients.ToList();
                foreach (var data in childData)
                {
                    context.Ingredients.Remove(data).Recipe_Id = id;

                }
                context.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
            }

            Models.Recipee objreci = new Models.Recipee();
            objreci = db.Recipees.Where(x => x.Recipe_Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            db.Recipees.Remove(objreci);
            db.SaveChanges();
           // return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", Recipe_Id);
    }
```